# What is the correct? "the following rules and regulations" or "following rules and regulations" (using definite article "the")

Tags: definite-article

Please let me know which one is correct.

- The vessel would be built in compliance with ***the*** following rules and regulations: ~~~
- The vessel would be built in compliance with ***the*** following rules and ***the*** regulations: ~~~
- The vessel would be built in compliance with following rules and regulations: ~~~

I think the definite article("***the***") after "***and***" can be omitted like the first sentence.
Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The first example --

> The vessel would be built in compliance with the following rules and regulations: ~~~

-- is the correct one. In this instance, "rules and regulations" is a common expression on its own, so it wouldn't get broken up. Also, the "the" is paired with "following" rather than "rules and regulations" for a similar reason.

If you had "the following rules and the regulations," and a person tried to take its meaning as written, it would mean that the vessel would be built according to the rules that are listed below, as well as the regulations that were probably mentioned at some other time prior. That doesn't make sense though, even if you had additional context, because it's too similar to the correct way of writing it that a reader would assume it was a typo.

Good question!

Comment: Thanks for your good answer.